# Magento "singleton/core/resource" already exists error

Tags: magento, runtime-error

```
Mage registry key "_singleton/core/resource" already exists

Trace:
#0 /.../app/Mage.php(222): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /.../app/Mage.php(476): Mage::register('_singleton/core...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource))
#2 /.../app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(141): Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')
#3 /.../app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(234): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->__construct('core_setup')
#4 /.../app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /.../app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /.../app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /.../index.php(104): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

Hi i'm getting above error, From few blogs and community forums i came to know the problem is with cache. so i added this in index.php

```
$app = Mage::app();
if ($app != null)
{
    $cache = $app->getCache();
    if ($cache != null)
    {
        $cache->clean();
    }
}
```

Original source: http://vipinsahu.com/magento-mage-registry-key-_singletoncoreresource-already-exists#ixzz24XXCt6m2

But still i'm getting the same. Please give me your idea to solve this issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh your magento cache on

> admin > system > cache management

click button refresh magento cache and delete all folder on your ../var/cache/